# Absolute path to file throws error?

Tags: node.js, module, path, require, absolute

Recently I started with NodeJS and I found the *require()* function.

I have two JS files:
main.js in **C:/Users/Admin** folder and,
test.js in **F:** drive

Here is my test.js file:

```
function log(name) {
    console.log(name);
}
module.exports.log = log;
```

and here is my main.js file:

```
var myModule = require("/F:/test");
myModule.log("Anonymous");
```

But when I type...
**C:\Users\Admin>node main.js**
in Node.js CMD, I get the following error statement:

**Error: Cannot find module '/F:/test'**

Help me to figure out the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving the path of the file wrong.

**It should be** `F:/test` **instead of** `/F:/test`.

You can use `path` module to resolve the path by `path.resolve` and check what it resolves to. In your case it is resolving to `C:\F:\test`.

**Update**

You can check to what your provided path resolves to like below

```
const path = require('path');
let p = path.resolve('/F:/test');
console.log(p);// C:\F:\test
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was stucked in this for past two hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use path module instead of specifying explicit path separators.

```
var path = require('path');
modulepath = path.join('F:','test');
var myModule = require(modulepath);
```